# intel Haxm is running but not recognized by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-x86, intel-haxm

Im using **android studio3.6.1 on windows10**. I have installed  **intelhaxm** but it's not recognized by android studio. as you see in pic1 its running [image: pic1] 
 but it is NOT recognized as *installed* in android studio [image: pic2] and [image: pic3] 
  **downloading in android studio sdk manager fails** see here [image: pic 4].
 generated log when it fails:

```
2020-03-20 21:48:13,109 [ 451055]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,109 [ 451055]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,109 [ 451055]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,109 [ 451055]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0-rc1\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,109 [ 451055]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,109 [ 451055]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,125 [ 451071]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\docs\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,125 [ 451071]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,125 [ 451071]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,125 [ 451071]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,125 [ 451071]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\auto\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,125 [ 451071]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,125 [ 451071]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\constraint\constraint-layout-solver\1.0.2\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,140 [ 451086]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\constraint\constraint-layout\1.0.2\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,140 [ 451086]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,140 [ 451086]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,140 [ 451086]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,140 [ 451086]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,140 [ 451086]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,140 [ 451086]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-25\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis\x86\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-automotive/sys-img2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading http s://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading http s://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,156 [ 451102]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading http s://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear-cn/sys-img2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,172 [ 451118]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading http s://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/sys-img2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,172 [ 451118]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading http s://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,172 [ 451118]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/plugins/sdk-updates/offline-repo/offline-repo.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,172 [ 451118]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading http s://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,172 [ 451118]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading http s://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:13,172 [ 451118]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading http s://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon2-1.xml
2020-03-20 21:48:15,859 [ 453805]   INFO - j.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper - using cached plugin list (updated at 3/20/2020 9:41 PM)
2020-03-20 21:48:24,435 [ 462381]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Packages to install:

2020-03-20 21:48:24,435 [ 462381]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
2020-03-20 21:48:24,435 [ 462381]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger -
```

2020-03-20 21:48:24,513 [ 462459]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)".
2020-03-20 21:48:24,513 [ 462459]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_5_6.zip
2020-03-20 21:48:39,181 [ 477127]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" ready.
2020-03-20 21:48:39,181 [ 477127]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
2020-03-20 21:48:39,181 [ 477127]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" complete.
2020-03-20 21:49:03,191 [ 501137]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Preparing "Uninstall Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)".
2020-03-20 21:49:03,191 [ 501137]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - "Uninstall Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" ready.
2020-03-20 21:49:03,191 [ 501137]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - "Uninstall Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" complete.
2020-03-20 21:49:03,191 [ 501137]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - "Uninstall Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" finished.
2020-03-20 21:49:03,222 [ 501168]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,222 [ 501168]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,222 [ 501168]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,222 [ 501168]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,238 [ 501184]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0-rc1\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,238 [ 501184]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,238 [ 501184]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,238 [ 501184]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\docs\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,238 [ 501184]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,238 [ 501184]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,238 [ 501184]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,238 [ 501184]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\auto\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,254 [ 501200]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,254 [ 501200]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\constraint\constraint-layout-solver\1.0.2\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,254 [ 501200]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\constraint\constraint-layout\1.0.2\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,254 [ 501200]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,254 [ 501200]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,254 [ 501200]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,269 [ 501215]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,269 [ 501215]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,269 [ 501215]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-25\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,269 [ 501215]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,269 [ 501215]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,269 [ 501215]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis\x86\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:03,269 [ 501215]   INFO - d.HaxmWizard$SetupProgressStep - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:06,269 [ 504215]   INFO - ols.idea.sdk.wizard.HaxmWizard - Package 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' does not appear to be installed - ignoring
2020-03-20 21:49:06,284 [ 504230]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed to update status to COMPLETE
com.android.repository.api.PackageOperation$StatusChangeListenerException: HAXM setup failed!
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.install.HaxmInstallListener.statusChanged(HaxmInstallListener.java:57)
at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.updateStatus(AbstractPackageOperation.java:508)
at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.complete(AbstractPackageOperation.java:207)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.completePackages(InstallTask.java:173)
at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:408)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-03-20 21:49:06,284 [ 504230]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Android Studio 3.6.1  Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
2020-03-20 21:49:06,284 [ 504230]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - JDK: 1.8.0_212-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
2020-03-20 21:49:06,284 [ 504230]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - OS: Windows 10
2020-03-20 21:49:06,284 [ 504230]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Last Action: Android.RunAndroidSdkManager
2020-03-20 21:49:06,284 [ 504230]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" failed.
2020-03-20 21:49:06,284 [ 504230]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed packages:
2020-03-20 21:49:06,284 [ 504230]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
2020-03-20 21:49:08,362 [ 506308]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,362 [ 506308]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,362 [ 506308]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,362 [ 506308]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,362 [ 506308]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0-rc1\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,362 [ 506308]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,362 [ 506308]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,378 [ 506324]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\docs\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,378 [ 506324]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,378 [ 506324]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,378 [ 506324]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,378 [ 506324]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\auto\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,378 [ 506324]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,378 [ 506324]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\constraint\constraint-layout-solver\1.0.2\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,394 [ 506340]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\m2repository\com\android\support\constraint\constraint-layout\1.0.2\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,394 [ 506340]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,394 [ 506340]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,394 [ 506340]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,394 [ 506340]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,394 [ 506340]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,394 [ 506340]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-25\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,394 [ 506340]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,409 [ 506355]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,409 [ 506355]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis\x86\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,409 [ 506355]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
2020-03-20 21:49:08,675 [ 506621]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appDefaultFont took 16 ms
2020-03-20 21:49:10,237 [ 508183]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appProjectViewSharedSettings took 16 ms
2020-03-20 21:49:10,284 [ 508230]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplicationjojo' My Application jojoKotlin2JvmCompilerArguments took 16 ms, libraryTable took 16 ms
2020-03-20 21:49:18,329 [ 516275]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 15 ms
2020-03-20 21:49:18,345 [ 516291]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplicationjojo' My Application jojoUnloadedModulesList took 16 ms

**important:**  *https* links are ok in original log file. I inserted space to change them because of "*You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links.*" rule. 
**note**: virtualization is enabled , and hyper-v is disabled 
extracting intelhaxm-android.exe using 7zip and running setup.exe manually didn't work.

Comment: What did the intel HAXM installation log indicate the reason the installation failed?  Edit your question with only the relevant information from the log in question.

Comment: important : https links are ok in original log file. I inserted space to change them because of  "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links." rule.

Comment: @Ramhound log file attached .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve solved it.
**reason :** for some reason android studio is not able to change state of HAXM setup. 
 there is a tricky point here: android studio installs haxm by itself and does NOT care if it’s installed before or not! if it’s installed, it just updates haxm.

**solution :** uninstall android studio (it’s better to remove all files and folders) and then follow these links step by step: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows#disable-devguard

now install a fresh android studio and be sure you check AVD option in install process.
(there is only two option at installation menu, check them both)
now it works.