# VirtualBox on Windows 10 PC causing BSOD due to IntelHaxm not running?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I've used VirtualBox for years, but it the last few weeks, I've been experiencing BSODs / computer freezing up.

I've checked the system logs and it's always the same error due to IntelHaxm not running.  I've tried updating all the drivers, and reinstalling Windows 10, but so far nothing has helped.

I'm considering doing a clean install of the OS, but was hoping to get any insight as to what's causing this.

[image]

Comment: Does this help you?   ...............   https://superuser.com/questions/1534243/intel-haxm-is-running-but-not-recognized-by-android-studio

Comment: [Intel HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm) was discontinued over a year ago and is not required for VirtualBox (VirtualBox never required it) nor does Android Studio currently require it

Comment: Have this problem arrived after an update of VirtualBox ?